# How to check a data on a file before uploading to a database?

Tags: java, sql

please i want to know if there is any way  i can check a particular data on  a file before uploading it to a database using java....to be precise.
for example the csv file contents the following records

```
idnumber courseCode Grade 
12/073.      CPE302.     A
12/074.      CPE302.     B
12/075.      CPE302.      C
```

In the database the following record exist in the table in which i want to upload the file.

```
12/073.     CPE302.    F
```

Is there a way i can check the file where 12/073  CPE302 A and replace it, and all other records are uploaded i.e

```
12/074. CPE302. B
12/075  CPE302. C
```

Comment: Yes, there is a way. You can compare the entries with the ones in the database. Since you have shown no code at all, nobody can help you.

Comment: If you have an array of records from the file and an array of records from the database then I imagine you can loop over one array and compare its values to those in the other array, adjusting and filtering as needed.  What have you tried and where are you stuck?

Answer (score 0):

The question is not very clear, but you could have a UNIQUE Constraint in the database on your table

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX ux_your_super_index ON YOUR_TABLE(idnumber, courseCode, Grade);
```

Then just insert the data in the file in the database. Whenever the data is already present in the database, an exception will prevent it from being inserted.